# Invalid operand to binary expression Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I'm trying to write this swift line in Objective-C.

*Swift*

```
timeRemainingLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d", ((lround(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), lround(timeRemaining) % 60)
```

*Objective-C*

```
timeRemainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", ((roundf(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), roundf(timeRemaining) % 60];
```

But it gives this error:

> Invalid operand to binary expression Error.('float' and 'float')

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
CGFloat timeRemaining = 109.13;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", ((int)(roundf(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), ((int)roundf(timeRemaining) % 60)];
NSLog(@"String = %@", string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the results of `roundf` into integers. 
Your line should look something like this

> timeRemainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d",
>   (((int)roundf(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), (int)roundf(timeRemaining) %
>   60];

Edit: The working answer from a comment:

```
CGFloat timeRemaining = 109.13;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", ((int)(roundf(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), ((int)roundf(timeRemaining) % 60)];
NSLog(@"String = %@", string);
```

Comment: while i run Swift code it will display perfect time of avplayer current player duration but when i write in Objective C it will return wrong value

Comment: How about `timeRemainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", (int)((roundf(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), (int)(roundf(timeRemaining) % 60)];`?

Comment: it will give me same error what i have posted in my question.

Comment: I just tested the following and it worked: `CGFloat timeRemaining = 109.13;NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", ((int)(roundf(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), ((int)roundf(timeRemaining) % 60)];NSLog(@"String = %@", string);`

Answer (score 0):

```
try dividing with decimal value. i.e. **/60.0f** instead of **/60**

timeRemainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d", ((roundf(timeRemaining) / 60) % 60), roundf(timeRemaining) % 60];
```

Comment: did you try to write this in ur Objective C project? it will give same error as i post in question